# Can an Inno-Setup ISS script include an external ISS script file?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating an installation script that I'd like to break up into smaller, more manageable pieces. Is there a way for an Inno Script file to have an INCLUDE or a reference to another ISS script file that is separate and has a different function overall to play during installation but becomes an integrated part of the full installation itself?

Consider:
ProgramInstall.iss
SQLInstall.iss
SOAPInstall.iss

ProgramInstall would have an include to the other scripts and return one full EXE that did the job as if they were all in one large file.

Not only would this be helpful for management purposes but would allow me to reuse scripts that are tested and working with other main application installation projects. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What is your innosetup project file structure (after spliting in several files)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well - I guess finding the right section of the CHM file is always helpful:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptformatoverview

Inno-Setup seems to include an C-like `#include` directive.

> A C-like `#include` directive is supported, which pulls in lines from a
> separate file into the script at the position of the `#include`
> directive. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> #include "filename.txt"
> ```
>
> If the filename is not fully qualified, the compiler will look for it
> in the same directory as the file containing the `#include` directive.
> The filename may be prefixed by "`compiler:`", in which case it looks
> for the file in the compiler directory.